# How to define string containing special symbols in pro file in QT?

Tags: string, qt, character

I need to define something like this:

```
DEFINES += SENSOR_URL="udp://10.3.2.2.220#1"
```

but it throws error:

> Error:Missing closing " quote

How to do that?

Comment: show what you tried...

Comment: I've tried DEFINES += SENSOR_URL=\\\"udp://10.3.2.2.220#1\\\". But it throws: missing terminating " character.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe the title of this thread should be changed to reflect that the problem is with .pro files instead of a Qt string (QString).

Answer (score 11):

I do something like this in my pro files:

```
DEFINES += VERSION_STR=\\\"0.4\\\"
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem could be that the '#' character is a comment marker in qmake files format, so it should be escaped. Something like this:

```
DEFINES += SENSOR_URL=\\\"udp//:10.3.2.2.220$${LITERAL_HASH}1\\\"
```

Comment: Ok. Now error changed to: <command-line>:0: Error:'udp' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Thank you Sir, the `$${LITERAL_HASH}` was exactly what i needed.

Comment: Just to clarify, `$${LITERAL_HASH}` is a built-in QMake variable.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is the `#` is treated as a comment, which is what's causing it to ignore the closing quote. Unfortunately, it's a non-escapable special character, even using `quote` and `escape_expand` and other undocumented functions. There was [some discussion on the bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-18673) of fixing it, but it's been closed.

Answer (score 1):

A working example from a project here:

```
 DEFINES += REPO_DIR="\\\"$$DESTREPODIR\\\""
```